# how to print nested array in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know its very basic stupid question. But I just started now sp don't know how to proceed. I am trying to display array store is one object. object is inside controller. But I am not able to print it. please let me know where I am mistaking.

Here' my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
         content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController as dishCtrl">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p>Put the dish details here</p>
                
                <div class="media" >
                    
                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                    <a href="#">
                    <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dishCtrl.dish.image}}>
                    </a>
                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                
                        <h2 class="media-heading">{{dishCtrl.dish.name}}S
                        <span class="label label-danger">{{dishCtrl.dish.label}}</span>
                        <span class="badge">{{dishCtrl.dish.price | currency}}</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p>{{dishCtrl.dish.description}}</p>
                       
                        </div>
                    
                
                
            
        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
                 <blockquote ng-repeat="commenta in dishCtrl.dish.comments">
                        <p>{{commenta.rating}}</p>
                        </blockquote>
             
            </div>
        
    </div>
    

    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);
        
        app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {

            var dish={
                          name:'Uthapizza',
                          image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                          category: 'mains', 
                          label:'Hot',
                          price:'4.99',
                          description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }
                               
                           ]
                    };
            
            this.dish = dish;
            
        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A code without **clear problem statement** is off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have declared the code outside the controller div. It must be like this :

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController as dishCtrl">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <p>Put the dish details here</p>

    <div class="media">

      <div class="media-left media-middle">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dishCtrl.dish.image}}>
        </a>

      </div>
      <div class="media-body">

        <h2 class="media-heading">{{dishCtrl.dish.name}}S
                    <span class="label label-danger">{{dishCtrl.dish.label}}</span>
                    <span class="badge">{{dishCtrl.dish.price | currency}}</span>
                    </h2>
        <p>{{dishCtrl.dish.description}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
  <blockquote ng-repeat="commenta in dishCtrl.dish.comments">
    <p>{{commenta.rating}}</p>
  </blockquote>

</div>
</div>
```

Here is the [updated code](http://plnkr.co/edit/ysrsGPO0kAbPNwhedZhh?p=preview)

Hope it helps :)